# Solve differential equasion $(y'')^2-5y'+6=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve differential equation  $(y'')^2-5y'+6=0$

For there is no "x" in equation, I made substitution $y'=p(y)$ and $y''=p'p$

$(p'p)^2-5p+6=0$

What can I do with the squared member?

Comment: Solve for it and take the square root?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y'=p$, then $$(y'')^2-5y'+6=0 \implies p'^2-5p+6=0 \implies p'= \sqrt{6-5p}. $$$$\int\frac{dp}{\sqrt{6-5p}}=\int dx+A \implies -\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{6-5p}=x+A.$$
$$\implies p=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6}{5}-\frac{5}{4}(x+A)^2 \implies y=\frac{6x}{5}-\frac{5}{12}(x+A)^3+B$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(p'p)^2-5p+6=0$$
Continue....
$$\dfrac {dp}{dy}p=\pm\sqrt {5p-6}$$
$$\int \dfrac {p}{\sqrt {5p-6}}dp=\pm \int dy$$

But you don't need any substitution:
$$(y'')^2-5y'+6=0$$
$$\dfrac {dy'}{dx}=\pm \sqrt {5y'-6}$$
it's separable:
$$\int \dfrac {dy'}{ \sqrt {5y'-6}}=\pm \int dx$$
$$\dfrac 1 5\int \dfrac {d(5y'-6)}{ \sqrt {5y'-6}}=\pm (x+C)$$
$$\dfrac 2 5{ \sqrt {5y'-6}}=\pm (x+C)$$
$$\dfrac 4 {25}(  {5y'-6})= (x+C)^2$$
That you can easily solve.